# Uploading browser extension to Microsoft Partner Centre

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I currently have continuous integration that updates an extension on Chrome Web Store and Mozilla Add On Market, however I am now trying to make a script that uploads to the Microsoft Partner Centre. Does anyone know how to upload via API to this Microsoft Partner Centre? (Specifically for Browser Extensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found it particularly hard to write a script that would do this, so hard that I had to use Selenium due to all the JS loaded on the Microsoft Partner Centre sites. Never the less, I have written a script that will login, upload a new version and publish it (note that it won't work unless you've created and uploaded the first version of your extension yourself).

https://gist.github.com/8W9aG/d135f2780e2dc27baa682bae3a2a1cc7

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft just released the [Microsoft Edge Add-Ons API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/api/using-addons-api) which finally gives the ability to programmatically upload browser extensions to the web store via an API.

If you're using Node, can use the [Edge Webstore Upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@plasmohq/edge-addons-api) package to work with this API.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to upload Edge extension to Partner Center using some API? Partner Centre does not have such an API to provide to upload extensions. Correct me if I misunderstand what you want.

If you want to upload Edge extension, please refer to [Publish your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension). If you want to update Edge extension, please refer to [Update An Extension Listing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/update).

Comment: I do want to update the edge extension programmatically, preferably by API

Comment: @user293895 Microsoft Partner Center doesn't have such a function for now. If you need this feature, please provide your feedback to the official website. At the bottom of the page, there's a [product feedback button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eChhC.png) you can click to send your feedback.